# How to add a media attribute to the CSS LINK html tag for the ASP.NET WebResource.axd Http Handler

Tags: c#, iphone, css, webresource.axd

The ASP.NET WebResource.axd Http Handler is used to serve resources embedded in DLL's.

The LINK html tag is automatically generated by ASP.NET.

I would like to intercept the generation of the LINK html tag for a certain set of embedded CSS from a third party DLL and add a media attribute.

**In summary:**

I would like to add a Media attribute to the LINK html tag for the ASP.NET WebResource.axd Http Handler.

So this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WebResource.axd?d=XXXXX" />
```

Appears like this:

```
<link media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
 href="/WebResource.axd?d=XXXXX" />
```

Cheers

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I follow: what's the question you're asking, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround. Firstly, links like this are being added to the `Page`'s head. Your page must have `runat=”server”` in the `<head>` tag for the automatic style sheet inclusion. The pages created by the IDE have this setting automatically. So, links being added is a `HtmlLink` control type. The idea is to iterate through controls in `Page`'s header, find `HtmlLink` controls and set necessary attribute (or even attributes). I include this into the `Page_Load` event:

```
Page.Header.Controls
    .OfType<HtmlLink>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(link =>
    {
        link.Attributes["media"] = "screen and (min-device-width: 481px)";
    });
```

Before this I had:

```
<head id="Header">
    <title></title>
    <link href="App_Themes/MyTheme/main.css" 
          type="text/css" 
          rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

and after the result is:

I know, this uses `Themes` insted of `WebResource.axd` but for the last one the result will be the same.

The latest thing: there may be another links in the page. So it would be good to recognize *our* links (the links need to be modified). So if there is no `id` attribute you could recognize them by `href` attribute.